# What is expected in a 5-minute presentation for a Phd interview?

Tags: phd, presentation

I was called for an interview for a Ph.D. program. They asked me to prepare a 5minute presentation to give my view on how I would work as a researcher in their institution and how I would approach the research project. I am not sure what kind of infromation should be included in my presentation.

Comment: What country? .

Comment: Try to convey passion and sketch your hopefully reasonable idea. Avoid bio and decoration.